# hidden friend in a class template name clashes with another symbol in inline namespace

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, customization-point

I'd like to provide a hidden friend for my type, and at the same time there is another object with the same name in an inline namespace. Everything works fine with normal types.

But if I have a template, the compiler errors when I instantiate the template

```
redefinition of 'cpo' as different kind of symbol
```

Here is the code:

```
namespace lib{

    struct CPO{
        template<typename... T>
        constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(T&&... args) const{
            cpo(static_cast<T&&>(args)...);
        }
    };

    inline namespace cpo_impl_{
        inline constexpr CPO cpo{};
    }

    struct Foo1{
        friend auto cpo(Foo1){
            return 5;
        }
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct Foo2{
        friend auto cpo(Foo2){
            return 6;
        }
    };
}

int main(){
    lib::Foo1 f1{};
    lib::cpo(f1); // works fine;

    lib::Foo2<int> f2{}; // error here
}
```

The smaller example is here

```
namespace lib{

    inline namespace impl_{
        inline constexpr int foo = 5;
    }

    template <typename T>
    struct Bar{
        friend auto foo(Bar){
            return 4;
        }
    };
}

int main(){
    lib::bar<int> b{};
}
```

btw, I am aware of other techniques such as `tag_invoke` but here I have no control of the names and the library

Comment: You are using Clang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is well-formed. This is [Clang Bug 37556](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37556).

> Compiling this well-formed program with -std=c++2a:
>
> ```
> namespace X {
>     inline namespace Y { int swap; }
>
>     template<class>
>     struct S {
>         friend void swap(S&, S&) {}
>     };
> }
>
> int main() {
>     X::S<int> s1, s2;
>     swap(s1, s2);
> }
> ```
>
> produces diagnostics (https://godbolt.org/g/ceWLxY):
>
> ```
> <source>:6:21: error: redefinition of 'swap' as different kind of symbol
>         friend void swap(S&, S&) {}
>                     ^
> <source>:11:15: note: in instantiation of template class 'X::S<int>' requested here
>     X::S<int> s1, s2;
>             ^
> <source>:2:30: note: previous definition is here
>     inline namespace Y { int swap; }
>                             ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```
>
> Note that the program compiles successfully if S is replaced by a
> non-template class. Discussion on the CWG reflector verified that this
> program is well-formed, including Richard's statement "Oops, Clang's
> redeclaration check in the template instantiation case is incorrectly
> performing a redeclaration lookup as if for a qualified name here,
> rather than a redeclaration lookup for an unqualified name."

No timeline for a fix however.

---

As a workaround, you can wrap `Foo2` in its own `inline namespace`

```
inline namespace disambig_detail {
  template <typename T>
  struct Foo2{
    friend auto cpo(Foo2){
        return 6;
    }
  };
}
```

This should alter the declarative region enough to avoid the mis-diagnosis. Meanwhile name lookup should proceed pretty much the same as if the namespace wasn't there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. what would be a good workaround to make it compile on all of gcc, msvc, and clang as of now?

Comment: thanks again. that seems to fix the issue on clang. I didn't realise that nothing works on MSVC yet. (even my previous example without template)

Comment: @dfri - Good point. It's possible that that internal linkage could prove bothersome, I suppose. A named namespace would do the same.

Comment: to make MSVC happy, I have to put the template struct inside a namespace , let's say `foo`, and I have to `using namespace foo` under `namespace lib`